# DKIM verification fails on AWS SES and Cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare, amazon-ses

I cannot get my DKIM settings verified with Amazon Web Services SES (Simple Email Service) and Cloudflare. The CNAME records provided by AWS seem to be configured on Cloudflare correctly, yet I am notified by AWS that DKIM verification fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Cloudflare CNAME records are proxied, which is one often expects:

[image]

However, that should not be so with DKIM records. Edit the DKIM CNAME records to set them in DNS only mode:

[image]